# Data exchange from Terrasync to QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps, trimble

What method could I use to import *.ssf files from Trimble GPS as features to display in QGIS?

Comment: This link to an older thread might be relevant [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42428/can-ssf-files-from-trimble-gps-be-imported-as-features-to-display-in-arcmap)...as it deals with converting those .ssf files to .shp files

Answer (score 2):

Use Trimble's GPS Pathfinder Office software "Export" feature to transform the SSF to a shapefile (shp).

Answer (score 0):

I found this:
https://www.neigps.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Exporting-TerraSync-SSF-files-to-Esri-Shapefiles-from-GNSS-Device.pdf

I'm not sure it's exactly what you are looking for, but it's a much simpler way of exporting a shapefile directly from you device instead of having to use pathfinder

Comment: Briefly summarize what is in the linked PDF in case the link is removed.